# Drupal fivestar and flag bookmark implementation

Tags: css, drupal, flags, drupal-fivestar

I'm looking for some advice on the best way to implement a fivestar rating system and flag bookmark system for nodes.

Design considerations for me focus on: similar styles for each, lightweight, and easy to move around page layouts - perhaps in blocks?

Any answers that help point me in a direction of how to go about this would be most helpful.

Comment: You can search for modules at Drupal.org - http://drupal.org/project/modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check these modules:
[Fivestar](http://drupal.org/project/fivestar)
[Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag)